# Entity Framework, Composite Key. Updating foreign key records

Tags: entity-framework, collections, model

I have a reservation class which contains a collection of bookings.
A booking has a `startDate` and an `endDate`.

If I have 2 bookings (date format: dd/MM/yyyy):

```
booking1.startDate = 01-04-2015
booking1.endDate = 03-04-2015

booking2.startDate = 03-04-2015
booking2.endDate = 10-04-2015
```

Then I can create a movement from booking1 to booking2.

My movement class has a composite primary key: `{fromBooking.Id, toBooking.Id}`
when in this instance `fromBookingId = booking1.Id` and `toBookingId = booking2.id`

This all works. My question is what should I do we we create a 3rd booking resulting in the following updates to our bookings collection:

```
booking1.startDate = 01-04-2015
booking1.endDate = 02-04-2015

booking3.startDate = 02-04-2015
booking3.startDate = 06-04-2015

booking2.startDate = 06-04-2015
booking2.endDate = 10-04-2015
```

The movement table will require the existing movement row to be deleted and 2 new rows inserted.

Should I manually check all movements for each update of a booking on a reservation and delete those that have been deprecated?

Or is there a more elegant solution to this perhaps using triggers on the Db?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Both "from" bookings and "to" bookings have start- and end dates? Then what is "from" and "to"? And what kind of booking is the third one, "from", "to"? Which foreign key does it take? I have a feeling you should reevaluate the whole booking system. Also, in the second list of bookings *all* bookings are different, so how would you store the changes by only replacing one record by two?

Comment: Hi Gert, a movement record illustrates a transition between 2 bookings. A movement record references the booking we are moving from using a FK called fromBookingId. It references the booking we are moving to using a FK called toBookingId. both these FK's also form the composite key of the movement class table.  StartDate and EndDate are attributes of booking. A booking Id remains the same when we update these dates.

Comment: When we add the third booking we update the dates of the first 2 bookings to ensure that only one booking is applicable at any point in time. The issue is reflecting these updates when creating / updating movements.